# MySQL RegExp Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from RegExp

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

My regular expression is this:

```
((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)).*?(\d+).*?((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)).*?(\d+).*?([a-z])
```

If I give this as input to MySQL RegExp I get the repetition operator error.I know it occurs because of ?: and I replaced it with ^ and I also replace * ? with [^>]* an my replaced regular expression is this:

```
'((^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)).[^>]*.(\\d+).[^>]*.((^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)).[^>]*.(\\d+).[^>]*.([a-z])'
```

The above expression executes with no errors but the matching fails and returns wrong results.So I want to convert the first regular expression to a POSIX standard supported by mysql without loosing the constraints.

Comment: MySQL does not support `.*?` lazy quantifiers

Comment: Yeah that's why I replaced it with [^>]*.

Comment: FYI, added explanation about the changes to convert the expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most important transformation needed is mimicking the lazy quantifier, which does not exist in MySQL. To do this, as you'll see in point 3 of the explanation, we will use mutually-incompatible expressions.

This should do it:

```
(([a-z][a-z0-9_]*))[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^a-z]*(([a-z][a-z0-9_]*))[^0-9]*([0-9]+)[^a-z]*([a-z])
```

Unless you plan to use them, you can also get rid in capturing parentheses in places such as `([0-9]+)` (where you had `(\d+)` before.)

**Explanation**

1. Replaced the `(?:` non-capturing groups with regular groups
2. Replaced `\d` with `[0-9]`
3. Replaced the lazy quantifiers with a negated character class that negates what is to follow, for instance `[^a-z]*` precedes `[a-z]`, and `[^0-9]*` precedes `[0-9]`